Solving the system $z^3=\frac{y}{x}- 2\frac{x}{y}$, $y^3 = \frac{x}{z}- 2\frac{z}{x}$, $z^3 = \frac{y}{x}- 2\frac{x}{y}$

Solve $x$, $y$, $z$.
$$\begin{align}
x^3 &= \frac{z}{y}- 2\frac{y}{z} \\[4pt]
y^3 &= \frac{x}{z}- 2\frac{z}{x} \\[4pt] 
z^3 &= \frac{y}{x}- 2\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}$$

The first approach was to add all the equations and apply any identities, but it isn't simplifying. Further, I just don't know how can these equations have the only solutions as $1$ or $-1$ only, maybe it's a boundary problem. I also cannot take much help of the fact that these equations are symmetric in $x$, $y$, and $z$.
Next I tried subtracting any 2 equations, but the denominators are creating problem, as I am forced to take LCM which further complicates the problem.
Any idea or hints??

What is the source of the problem ?

If we consider only real solutions, here is an elementary approach. Observe that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, so are $(x,-y,-z),(-x,y,-z)$ and $(-x,-y,z)$. Therefore, by flipping the signs of exactly two variables if necessary, we may assume that $x,y$ and $z$ are either all positive or all negative.
If all variables are positive, let $x\ge y\ge z>0$. Then $\frac{x}{z}\ge\frac{z}{y}$ and $\frac{2z}{x}\le\frac{2y}{z}$. Therefore
$$
y^3=\frac{x}{z}-\frac{2z}{x}
\ge\frac{z}{y}-\frac{2y}{z}=x^3
\ge y^3.
$$
and we must have $x=y$. But then $z^3=\frac{y}{x}-\frac{2x}{y}=-1<0$, which is a contradiction. Hence this case is impossible.
If all variables are negative, let $0>x\ge y\ge z$. Then $|z|\ge|y|\ge|x|>0$, $\frac{|x|}{|z|}\le\frac{|y|}{|x|}$ and $\frac{2|z|}{|x|}\ge\frac{2|x|}{|y|}$. Therefore
$$
y^3=\frac{|x|}{|z|}-\frac{2|z|}{|x|}
\le\frac{|y|}{|x|}-\frac{2|x|}{|y|}=z^3
\le y^3
$$
and we must have $y=z$. Substitute this into the three equations for $x^3,y^3$ and $z^3$, we see that the only solution is $x=y=z=-1$. So, without the assumption that all variables are negative, all other solutions are given by changing the values of two of the three variables to $1$.

Nice +1. For real solutions, perhaps simpler: $$xyz=\frac{y^2-2x^2}{z^2}=\frac{z^2-2y^2}{x^2}=\frac{x^2-2z^2}{y^2}=-1$$
$$\implies y^2+z^2=2x^2, \quad z^2+x^2=2y^2, \quad x^2+y^2=2z^2$$
Thus, $x^2, y^2, z^2$ are means of the other two, and checking any ordering  leads us to conclude $\implies x^2=y^2=z^2 \implies (x,y,z)\in {(-1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, 1)}$
using $xyz=-1$ and any permutations of those are solutions as well.

After an algebraic step you have,
$$x^3=\frac{z^2-2y^2}{yz}$$
$$y^3=\frac{x^2-2z^2}{zx}$$
$$z^3=\frac{y^2-2x^2}{xy}$$
thus,
$$x^2=\frac{z^2-2y^2}{xyz}$$
$$y^2=\frac{x^2-2z^2}{xyz}$$
$$z^3=\frac{y^2-2x^2}{xyz}$$
adding the above we find,
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{xyz}$$
and,
$$xyz=-1$$
This implies that one of the triplet of variables must be -1 and the other two must be +1. Take your pick, any permutation will solve the equation.

Minor typo: last $z^3$ should be $z^2$.

How to rule out the possibility that $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$?

Why does $xyz=-1$ imply that one is -1 and the other two 1?  If they have to be integers, maybe.

@user1551 assuming $x,y,z$ are real then $x^2$, $y^2$ and $z^2$ are all non-negative. So for their sum to be $0$, they must each be zero, meaning $x=y=z=0$, but this can't be possible since we are dividing by them

Nice solution, +1. Though you've missed off the situation where they're all $-1$

Why xyz=-1 implies one of them must be -1??

Did you assume $x, y, z$ are integers? Else why should they be $\pm1$?

[EDITED]
A Groebner basis computation in Maple gives
$$
\eqalign{z^{2} \left(z -1\right) \left(z +1\right) \left(z^{2}+z +1\right) \left(z^{2}-z +1\right) \left(z^{6}+z^{3}+7\right) \left(z^{6}-z^{3}+7\right)&= 0\cr
 z^{14}-8 z^{8}+63 y^{2}-56 z^{2} &= 0\cr 
z^{2} \left(y \,z^{15}+10 y \,z^{9}+52 y \,z^{3}+63 x \right) &= 0\cr 
-4 z^{14}-31 z^{8}+63 x^{2}-28 z^{2} &= 0
\cr} $$
i.e. $z$ must be one of the roots of the first equation (other than $0$), and then $y$ and $z$ can be found from the others.  The real roots of the first are $z = \pm 1$. The real solutions of your system are then
$(x,y,z) = (\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ where the number of $-$'s is either $1$ or $3$.
There are also complex solutions, such as (approximately)
$x = -1.151586959-0.7660147900 i $ , $y  = 0.08759478824 - 1.380310956 i$, $z =-1.239181747 + 0.6142961663 i $, where $x$ is a root of $z^6 + z^3 + 7 = 0$ while $y$ and $z$ are roots of $z^6 - z^3 + 7 = 0$.

I used a GB and found $$(x=-1\land y=-1\land z=-1)\lor (x=-1\land y=1\land z=1)\lor (x=1\land y=-1\land z=1)\lor (x=1\land y=1\land z=-1)$$ Did something incorrect get in my or in your equations when finding the GB?

This comment agrees with F. Wright's answer.

Oops, sign error.  I'll edit.

To elaborate on F. Wright’s answer, reformulate the system of equation as
\begin{align*}
\lambda x^2&=z^2-2y^2,\\
\lambda y^2&=x^2-2z^2,\\
\lambda z^2&=y^2-2x^2,\\
\lambda &=xyz
\end{align*}
where $x,y,z\in\mathbb C\setminus0$. The first three equations above can be further rewritten in matrix form as $(\lambda I-A)v=0$ where  $v=(x^2,y^2,z^2)^\top$ and
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&-2&1\\ 1&0&-2\\ -2&1&0}.
$$
As $x,y,z\ne0$, if a solution exists, $\lambda I-A$ must be singular. Hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^3+6\lambda+7=(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-\lambda+7)$. Therefore $A$ has three distinct eigenvalues $-1,\frac{1+i\sqrt{27}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-i\sqrt{27}}{2}$ and its eigenspaces are one-dimensional. It follows that
$$
\pmatrix{x^2\\ y^2\\ z^2}=k\pmatrix{\lambda^2+2\\ \lambda+4\\ 1-2\lambda}
$$
for some scalar $k$. Hence $\lambda^2=x^2y^2z^2=k^3(\lambda^2+2)(\lambda+4)(1-2\lambda)$, i.e., $k$ is a cubic root of
$$
\dfrac{\lambda^2}{(\lambda^2+2)(\lambda+4)(1-2\lambda)}.\tag{1}
$$
Given each choice of $\lambda$ (in the spectrum of $A$) and $k$, the original system of equations is solved by
$$
\pmatrix{x\\ y\\ z}=\pmatrix{\sqrt{k(\lambda^2+2)}\\ \sqrt{k(\lambda+4)}\\ \sqrt{k(1-2\lambda)}}\tag{2}
$$
where the complex square roots above are chosen such that $xyz=\lambda$. Note that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, so are $(x,-y,-z),(-x,y,-z)$ and $(-x,-y,z)$.
For real solutions we may simply pick $\lambda=-1,\,k=\frac{1}{3}$ and $(x,y,z)=(-1,-1,-1),(-1,1,1),(1,-1,1)$ or $(1,1,-1)$.
Complex solutions also exist. E.g. we may pick $\lambda = \frac{1+i\sqrt{27}}{2}$ and choose in $(1)$ and $(2)$
\begin{align*}
k &= 0.339533012438126 + 0.142292566835562i,\\
x &= 0.087594788238067 + 1.380310956214547i\\
y &= 1.239181747322821 + 0.614296166253989i\\
z &= 1.151586959084754 - 0.766014789960558i.
\end{align*}
